# How to measure voltage of a system with a different GND reference?

Tags: voltage, measurement, esp8266, diy

I want to measure and log the voltage of a "closed" system shown in the following schematic on the left side. This system has its own reference to GND which is not connected to the measurement system.

A common way to measure in the "Ardunio-world" is using a voltage divider. But this requires a shared GND reference.

My question is how to measure the voltage of the left system with reference to GNDD by the right (measurement) system? GNDD and GND cannot be connected together, because this would influence the other circuitry present on the left side (not shown here).

[image: Exemplary situation of two systems]

I found [these schematics](http://embedblog.eu/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/sheet2-1024x682.png) of [this](http://embedblog.eu/?p=298) project which basically creates a DMM but I don't get entirely why COM is connected to the 1.25V reference (which is also electrically connected to GND of the measurement system).

Any suggestions?

---

**Edit 1:** not directly relevant for the question but most of the answers reference these two "questions" / points:

- for my setup it is not important if the "measuring solution" takes some mA's from the left system
- the voltage of the left system will be in a range of 16V - 40V; of the right system 12V

Comment: Using a resistor divider is not specific to Aruduino land. Doing isolated measurements is challenging. The simplest might be to use your wemos board powered from the battery use WiFi for the isolation. If you’re worried about power consumption then add circuitry to power up/down the board at a regular interval or use an isolated dc/dc converter. There are other techniques like voltage to frequency and use an optocoupler or transformer for isolation. Considering the cost of esp32/8266 boards, it might be the cheapest and simplest solution.

Comment: Do you have any information at all on what the difference can be between GNDD & GND? As the question stands, answering is possible but your solutions can range from very cheap difference amplifiers, to sophisticated and expensive systems. Additionally, is there any reason why you cannot (weakly) couple the two grounds? Say, is it bad if you put a 1 MΩ resistor to connect them?

Comment: `I don't get entirely why COM is connected to the 1.25V reference` to measure negative voltages. Think of it as an offset.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem.  There's no point in trying to measure a voltage of 2 completely disconnected things; and any attempt to compare GNDD with GNDD is essentially connecting them - maybe via a big resistor, but none-the-less, still connecting.  Maybe it's better to ask how to connect GND and GNDD without impacting the rest of the system?

Comment: @Kartman I like your proposal which is really simple and it goes into the same direction as proposed by Gil further down. I think I'll go with this.

Comment: "range of 16V - 40V" Unfortunately, only now this important information is provided and it is well below of the value that demand isolated solutions, which are more appropriate and cost effective for common mode voltages of hundreds of Volts to kVs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest is to use an analog coupler such as the HCNR201. The down side to this is it draws current from the battery. This can be resolved with a small relay. Simply use the normally open contact to connect the battery when you want to take a reading turn it on, get the reading then turn it off. The impedance into the analog input on the Arduino is high but it requires a maximum of 10K to keep it stable for reading.

Comment: This is - to my opinion - a nice solution and also matches the basic idea from @Kartman (first comment to the question) who proposed an ESP8266/32 which can be used to measure and transmit without an electrical connection. I'll go one of them (yeah during a chip crisis probably with the ESP8266, because I have some of them ^^)

Answer (score 7):

Measure the voltage of '?', and the voltage of GNDD, simultaneously, then subtract.

A way to do this with one channel rather than two is to measure the difference between ? and GNDD with a differential amplifier.

Note that to do either of these, the difference between GND and GNDD must be constrained somehow, to limit the common mode voltage to be measured.

If the common mode voltage is too high or uncontrolled to do these measurements, then my favourite way of doing a cheap and cheerful isolated voltage measurement is to use a voltage controlled VCO, perhaps the VCO part of a 4046, or maybe you could use a 555 with its voltage control input, to drive an optocoupler to get pulses back to the microcontroller, which it could then count the frequency of.

Comment: This may not be simple if there's several kilovolts difference.

Comment: How about using a transformer with a bridge rectifier on the output which drives the collector and emitter of a transistor whose collector and base are connected to the voltage being measured?  Drive the transformer with a small current and see how much voltage appears on the primary.  Such a design might need calibration and it may not be possible to avoid variations with temperature, but it would avoid loading the device under test, and the transformer wouldn't need to carry as much current as would be needed to power a fancier circuit.

Comment: @supercat Yes, there are lots of ways to do it, I only mentioned an obvious way, and my favourite way. Perhaps you'd expand your way in an answer. Putting an ADC on the source and an opto link back to the micro is yet another way.

Comment: @Neil_UK: I haven't tried implementing the transformer approach, so I wouldn't feel confident enough to offer it as an answer.  If consuming power in the domain being measured would be acceptable, optos are probably cheaper than transformers, but if such power consumption is not acceptable I would think using a transformer to convey an analog measurement might be better.

Answer (score 2):

If the two ground references must be fully isolated, you need an isolated ADC system.

You can build one out of SPI-bus ADC chip, optoisolators and an isolated DC-DC converter.

There exists also integrated chips, such as ADE1201 that contains power isolation and data isolation for the ADC all on one chip:

[image: ADE1201 architecture]

Comment: That is an interesting IC I didn't know about. Thanks for sharing, I'll have a look.