# Check 5V differential input with unknown common mode offset (comparator)

Tags: comparator, common-mode

I want to output a +5V signal on my PCB when an external signal is 5V above its own ground level, but I don't know what the difference between the external and board ground might be (I hope "small", but that could mean anything...)

I'm concerned that if I used a comparator (like, perhaps, the [ADCMP391](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADCMP391_392_393.pdf)), a relative shift in the ground levels might give me input voltages significantly outside the Vcc/Gnd range.

Can I connect the board 5V and the input 5V/Gnd to a MOSFET or similar to produce a suitable output?

Alternatively, are there more suitable components to handle this type of situation? Perhaps a SPST relay with the coil connected to the external signal and the board 5V passing through the switch?

Comment: I've rolled-back your amendment because it invalidates my answer and, my answer was given before you made that amendment thus, if your modified question were viewed by someone now they would downvote my answer based on it being inappropriate. If you want to add your new requirement as an amendment then please do very carefully and with full respect to answers that are already given.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing as you were answering - I saw the answer after submitting the change. Rolling back is fine, and I'll continue to work through your answer, hopefully it will be enough for me to work this out and then I'll accept it.

Comment: If you use an extra opto-isolator, it can be used to detect the presence of a full connection providing the voltage is greater than at least 2 volts.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/612292/how-to-measure-voltage-of-a-system-with-a-different-gnd-reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the grounds are at different potentials, the safest is to isolate.

[image]

On the left, if there is enough voltage on the input to turn on the opto's LED, it will pull the output down. You can use a darlington opto, or a normal opto.

On the right, a TL431 is used as a comparator (see datasheet about how the threshold is calculated). When input voltage rises above 4.2V, it will turn on the opto's LED, and pull the output down.

Both will leave the output at high level if the input is disconnected.

If you want the opposite polarity, simply swap the opto's output transistor and the pullup resistor. Then when the opto is powered, it will pull the input up.

Without power on the input side, it is not possible to distinguish between "wires disconnected" and "0V", so that would require a more complicated circuit with an isolated power supply, or connecting the grounds to use power from the other side.

These circuits are pretty slow, especially the one with the comparator, they will work fine for a few kHz.

Comment: I think the TI ISO721M is going to be suitable for what I wanted, especially if I can separately provide a "VCC1" level, but even if I tie that to the input it will function as I wanted. Accepting this since it was closest to what I chose.

Answer (score 3):

> *I want to output a +5V signal on my PCB when an external signal is 5V
> above its own ground level*

If you can source a few microamps from your external signal without ruining it, you could power a low-power comparator and voltage reference that can make that decision. Then, if you also stored some extra energy from the remote signal into a capacitor, you could use the comparator to pulse drive an opto-isolator at a low rate and duty cycle. This can be detected using the opto-isolator's output on your PCB.

This delivers full galvanic isolation and no debate about common mode ground issues.

But, if you want high speed continuous monitoring and your external signal has limited energy then it can't be done this way. You need to decide what is feasible based on what you know about the external signal.

The most likely fall-back position is to use an attenuating differential amplifier with high common-mode rejection feeding a comparator (all powered by your PCB).

> *Can I connect the board 5V and the input 5V/Gnd to a MOSFET or similar
> to produce a suitable output?*

That doesn't sound like there's anything there that would be useful.

> *Alternatively, are there more suitable components to handle this type
> of situation? Perhaps a SPST relay with the coil connected to the
> external signal and the board 5V passing through the switch?*

If your external signal can drive a relay without disrupting its own voltage level then, an opto-isolator is a preferred solution in my opinion because you can use a comparator to make a more accurate prediction as to what is or what isn't above 5 volts. So, if you want fairly good precision you wouldn't use a relay because it may operate at 4 volts or less (for a 5 volt relay).

Comment: Ok, thanks - precision isn't required, the input is nominally +5 or 0 relative to its own ground, and can provide up to 20mA, so I'll look at the arrangement in your first paragraph, and compare it to your last paragraph (opto-isolator). I'll discard any thoughts regarding MOSFETs.

Comment: @chrisb2244 Isolation of digital (on/off) signals is so easy to do optically that it's likely to be the best method under most circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to measure a logic level of CMOS at 5V with an unknown floating power supply, and not one offline tied to AC Line.

I'm not sure if you care if the voltage is degraded by > 10 % or excessive, but if it is floating, connecting your load to it will minimize that common-mode voltage.  For noise immunity, you might want to define your environment and cable length but twisted pair is advised in any case.

Your sensing requirement is negative logic.

i.e. Out= high=5V when input is open and low= 0V when input is 5V.  This is normal for any common-emitter, CE switch. (they all invert, same with common-source in FET switches)

As an alternative option, [I can suggest all you need is a CE switch.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMkAcAWA7ATjigbGHojFinHkkgnAMwhwCmAtIogFABOSGFATGChC80EfoIiYYnISKECZojL3BJYbAC5DycwbxS75ERCCZxIcXhkI0RiLPcTamYc5etwBb7GGPEIAEwYAMwBDAFcAG3U2AHcFISUhfQTlMDYAc3jLZWEIGjA0FTSAJSTBRD0ykCwKCAkIBDqoOGk9csq2pCxU1TUAeRAaGgo7ZWHy7qK2ADckPkTEPkNKWUai82lFnRAUUWWPWKreYSPEtK5clO55nr80uK2xFSfeQ93tmu3XuMuX7RfDkMRpNOqMhIdFqJtKwctp7tcro8zhCKloKJ8nmkAB5zJAoYw4PGFQrEEDFAA6AGcAPZBKkAYQAsn0AMpUiLU9IASwAxmwcSwwHReHgeiKECSIEEOSF1FyAHbpKkKgAOYXUVPUDEpGsp6QY8v5eIwQiwwpOvE+kpAlJCQQY6gAnlTikbEGgsNwTZZfO9rZSeSEIgx-JrqVSaKgMAA1TUACw42rj1Ii-kgEIIaIRmLYIjoNH4QhOcB4g0LEAwAH0C5WwJWKpa62hIPZW2229ha9AYIhKyxK7xKyha0bSyKRgWhHhPdb1DEuTqQ1SVSEuRwqWwgA)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is often done by dividing down the input signal using a resistor network. The common mode gets down to a safe level, but the differential voltage goes down too. It’s no free lunch, since the comparator’s response is faster the higher the differential input.

This approach is used in instrumentation amplifiers that have a wide common mode range extending way past the supply rails - sometimes by 100s of Volts.

Ultimately, which solution would be most appropriate depends on what is the signal source and what are its parameters - voltage vs load current response, common mode voltage range, bandwidth of interest, etc. None of this is provided in the question, and all of it is important.